# Trying to number community event tickets

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I am trying to add sequential ticket numbers to Avery tickets with stubs. I have a background ticket image I use as a watermark and am looking to create the following using ms word. I am trying to use Avery word template : https://www.avery.com/templates/99154

[image: Tickets with stubs]

Comment: There are a number of methods of doing this. They were discussed on the Microsoft Answers forum: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/search/search?SearchTerm=sequentially%20number%20tickets&tab=&status=all&advFil=&IsSuggestedTerm=false&isFilterExpanded=undefined&CurrentScope.ForumName=msoffice&CurrentScope.Filter=msoffice_word&ContentTypeScope=&page=1&sort=Relevance&dir=Desc  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2013-tickets-sequentially-numbered/8062fb30-fd53-42fe-ac3b-a2e8da64e39a

Comment: Thank you so much for the article with links. I'll be doing this today.
Abbott

Comment: you are welcome